# C# WPF making a 7-day moving average

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hey i'm trying to make a 7-day moving average but i'm not sure how to go about it. What i currently have is The user enters values into a DataGrid and then after entering 7 numbers they get the average of those numbers (Sum of numbers / 7). I have managed to implement that, but i want to have a moving average so that when they enter the eight or the ninth value and so on they get a new average of the last 7 values. I'm not sure how i would go on about implementing that. So how it works right now is the user enter values into the DataGrid by typing the value into a TextBox called "AddWeightToGrid" Then the value goes into an ObservableCollectionsList called "gridListValues" and that's the DataGrids ItemSource (The DataGrid is called "WeightDataGrid"). Here's how the 7-day average calculation looks like right now:

```
    private void AddWeightToGridButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridListValues.Count <= 5)
            gridListValues.Add(new WeightGridValues { Weight = AddWeightToGrid.Text, Date = Convert.ToString(AddDateToGrid) });

        else if (gridListValues.Count >= 6)
        {
            gridListValues.Add(new WeightGridValues { Weight = AddWeightToGrid.Text, Date = Convert.ToString(AddDateToGrid), SevenDayWeightAverage = SevenDayAverageCalc(averageWeight) });                
        }
    }


     private string SevenDayAverageCalc(WeightGridValues averageWeight)
     {

        decimal sevenDayCalc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridListValues.Count; i++)
        {
            sevenDayCalc += Convert.ToDecimal(gridListValues[i].Weight);                
        }
        sevenDayCalc += Convert.ToDecimal(AddWeightToGrid.Text);
        sevenDayCalc = sevenDayCalc / 7;
        
        return averageWeight.SevenDayWeightAverage = Convert.ToString(sevenDayCalc);           

     }
```

I hope i did a good job explaining what my problem is and what i want to achieve. If i didnt please ask me to clarify. Any help is appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Best way is when you get seven items in list is to remove item zero from the object.

Comment: That could work but i want to save all the values in the grid if that makes sense. (Both the regular values and the average values) It seems quite complicated to do so though.

Comment: the get length of list and average the last 7.   If length is 10 you could skip the first three. gridListValues.Skip(gridListValues.Count - 7).Average(x => x.Weight);

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say im new to programming so i dont quite understand what the => thing is. I have realised this project might be a bit too much for my skill level right now. Probably best to put it on hold for a while until i have gotten better. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer from @jdweng is right, but probably need a little bit of explanation for @sharpus, since he/she is "new to programming".

Let me try to explain in a more basic way. Your SevenDayAverageCalc() is trying to traverse through the gridListValues one by one, get the sum, then divide by 7. This works fine if and only if your gridListValues has 7 elements. If there are more than 7 elements, you will need to skip the leading few and only use the last  7. So you could do this:

```
for (int i = gridListValues.count -7; i < gridListValues.count; i++)
{
    sevenDayCalc += Convert.ToDecimal(gridListValues[i].Weight);                
}
sevenDayCalc += Convert.ToDecimal(AddWeightToGrid.Text);
sevenDayCalc = sevenDayCalc / 7;
```

And this is actually what @jdweng's one line of code is doing: Skip the first few to reach [gridListValues.count - 7], then Average the rest of the elements' Weight. You may want to check out Skip https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=net-5.0 and Average https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=net-5.0